# laravel 5.7 job instance create but not execute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created jobs for video converting and updating in database in Laravel 5.7. All created jobs work correctly but any new job I am create in that only instance create but not execute. I have created one test email job with log entry.

My env file changes:
**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

In config folder:
**queue.php**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 400000,
        ],
```

Job called by cron job custom command:
**TestEmail.php**

```
MatchSendEmail::dispatch()->onQueue('queue_test');
```

My test mail job:
**MatchSendEmail.php**

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\EmailTest;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class MatchSendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        app('log')->info('supervisor send mail for all construct->');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        app('log')->info('supervisor send mail for all handle');
        $email = new EmailTest();
        Mail::to(['******@gmail.com', 'ravi@****.com'])->send($email);
        app('log')->info('supervisor send mail for all handle1');
    }
}
```

I have used supervisor for background process and below is configuration file:

```
[program:queue_test]

process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d

command=php /home/web1/******.com/htdocs/artisan queue:work --tries=10 --sleep=5

autostart=true

autorestart=true

user=web1

numprocs=20

redirect_stderr=true

stdout_logfile=/home/web1/******.com/htdocs/storage/logs/queue_test.log
```

Only job instance creates but not execute, please guide me how this issue resolve.

Answer (score 0):

As your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is set to `database` you need to run the below command to make the database table

```
php artisan queue:table
 
php artisan migrate
```

Then you need to start the worker by running the below command

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=30
```

Otherwise, for testing, you can set the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `sync` and run the job synchronously or you can call this below method to run the job without interacting with any queue

```
MatchSendEmail::dispatchNow()
```

Comment: is this MatchSendEmail::dispatchNow() work as back ground process?

Comment: When MatchSendEmail::dispatchNow() run will it affect to any other job in queue?

Comment: No, dispatchNow() will dispatch the job immediately, it will be not processed in background.

Comment: I want to process in background.

Comment: I already mentioned in the first solution how you can run the job in the background. You need to make the queue table and run php artisan queue:work --timeout=30

Comment: Thanks you help but sorry to say "php artisan queue:work --timeout=30" is not working for me also try with QUEUE_CONNECTION to sync  that also run job immediately.

Comment: Ummm. After running MatchSendEmail::dispatch()->onQueue('queue_test');, did this data inserted in your database?

Comment: Yes it's added to database jobs table

Comment: So then what do you seen when you run `php artisan queue:work --timeout=30` , it should pick those jobs from the database!

Comment: Noting is process when I was check jobs in database my job MatchSendEmail which is not working have null values of "maxTries":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null and previously created jobs which are currently working have values "maxTries":5,"timeout":0,"timeoutAt":null .

Comment: MatchSendEmail job insert in database `attempts` column value is 0 and when my working job insert it's `attempts` column value is 1.